# Join 3 mysql tables and retrieve all relevant data

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 sql tables

`product_data` - Stores all the details regarding the products

```
product_name  | description | ucode | heaven | star_rating | product_id
```

`product_images` - all the image urls with the photo id (each product has 1 or more images assigned)

```
img_url | photo_id
```

`product_img_map` - maps the correct images with the product

```
photo_id  | product_id
```

if i had the `product_id` in the `product_images` i could have easily joined them but there is a separate table that maps the photos with the products.

can someone tell me how can i query all the product details and the images for the products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` both tables into `product_data`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_data p
LEFT JOIN product_img_map im ON im.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images i ON i.photo_id = im.photo_id
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` to get product info even when there is no photo associated with that product.

Answer (score 0):

```
 product(product_id*)

 image(image_id*)

 product_image(product_id*,image_id*)

 * = (component of) PRIMARY KEY

 SELECT * 
   FROM product p 
   LEFT 
   JOIN product_image pi 
     ON pi.product_id = p.product_id
   LEFT
   JOIN image i
     ON i.image_id = pi.image_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine as many joins on as many keys as you like, since with every join, you specify the keys.

```
SELECT *
    FROM product_data
    LEFT JOIN product_img_map
        ON product_data.id=product_img_map.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_images
        ON product_images.id=product_img_map.photo_id
```

This variant with shortened table names is also frequently seen, but it's the same thing, just cosmetically different.

```
SELECT *
    FROM product_data d
    LEFT JOIN product_img_map m
        ON d.id=m.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_images i
        ON i.id=m.photo_id
```

You will get the lines for each product multiple times, once for each associated image. That's normal, but you will probably need to write some code to parse it. Making this easier is one reason ORMs ("Object Relational Mappers") are frequently used, which makes it easier to loop over data or images any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
select pi.img_url, pi.photo_id,pim.product_id,pd.* 
   FROM product_images as pi 
   left join product_img_map as pim on pim.photo_id  = pi.photo_id 
   left join product_data as pd on pd.product_id =  pim.product_id;
```

Please try above query.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do inner join. Try below

```
 select * from product_data pd
 left join product_img_map  im on pd. product_id = im.product_id
 left join product_images pi on im.photo_id   = pi.photo_id
```

I think left join is correct because there may be product with no photo associated with it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select * From product_data pd Inner JOin product_img_map pim on pd.product_id=pim.product_id Inner JOin product_images pm on pm.photo_id=pim.photo_id
```

Comment: Hello @downvoter, can you please tell what is wrong with the query if we compare it with the description provided by OP?

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from product_data pd left join product_img_map pim 
on pd.product_id = pim.product_id
left join product_images pi on
pim.photo_id = pi.photo_id
```